"Missing Dependencies" error in Drupal Module
Hope you all are doing well !!
I am a fresher here to Drupal, and my problem statement is as follows:
There is an existing Drupal code (.info and .module files only in repo), which needs to be promoted to Drupal9 which will contain .info.yml file, I have tried to manipulate existing one, but it throws error saying "Missing 'application'" which is added in my dependencies in .yml file. I am attaching screenshots for reference and looking forward for some dedicated support please to fix this error.
Note: The Drupal Module I am trying to install is on IBM product which is API connect Developer portal v10.0.5.x_lts.
I am adding these 2 files in a zip folder to install new Drupal module:
enter image description here
Error Seen :
enter image description here
New info.yml file
enter image description here
Existing .info file
enter image description here
Please let me know what other details I need to share to know more about the issue and what exactly I need to do in order to migrate the custom code as-is on Drupal higher versions.
Thanks & Regards,
All the info is in description

You are missing a custom or contrib module named "application"
